# Convergence of Averages of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, average

Let $\\{x_t^m\\}$ and $\\{y_t^{m}\\}$ be collections of sequences (for $m\in [1,2,\dots,M]$) converging to $x$ as $t\to\infty$. Furthermore, suppose that $||x_t^m - x|| \leq ||y_t^{m} - x||$ for all $t,m$.

Are there any assumptions that can be made so that statements about the distance of the average over $m$ of the respective collections of sequences from $x$ can be made? That is, I am curious about sufficient conditions for the following statement:

\begin{equation}
||\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^M x_t^m - x|| \leq ||\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^{M} y_t^{m} - x||
\end{equation}

For instance, one way to make this true is to assume a condition such that

\begin{equation}
||\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^M x_t^m - x|| = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^M ||x_t^m - x|| \leq \frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^M||y_t^{m} - x|| = ||\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^M y_t^{m} - x||
\end{equation}

For instance, if $x_t^m=y_t^{m}=x$, then this is (trivially) satisfied.

Are there other less trivial sufficient conditions where $||\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^M x_t^m - x|| \leq ||\frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^{M} y_t^{m} - x||$ holds?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I see, sorry for the poorly written question. I don't know if there is a formal solution, but I will edit the question for clarity and include some other information.

Comment: @mathemagics The question would be improved by removing any reference to $t$. The correct assumption is that $x^m\to x$ when $m\to \infty$. Also you could replace $x'$ with $y$ to avoid confusion. Finally, you are using a property of the triangle inequality which is not true. Revise the cases of equality in the triangle inequality.

Comment: I edited the question. I suppose I am struggling to provide the correct context for the question. What I am trying to ask about is collections of series that are pairwise related by the first inequality in the question above. For example, $x_t^m=\frac{1}{t^2}$, $y_t^m=\frac{1+m}{t^2}$. In particular, these do converge as $t\to\infty$, but there is also a dependence on $m$, so there are $2M$ series in question and we are averaging with respect to $m$.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\in \Bbb{N}^*$, let $x_n = \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$ and $y_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$. One has
\begin{equation}
\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*,\quad |x_n| < |y_n|
\end{equation}
but when $N\to\infty$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n \sim \frac{\log N}{N}\quad\text{but}\quad
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N} y_n \sim \frac{\log 2}{N}
\end{equation}
So the average of $x_n$ converges slower to $0$ than the average of $y_n$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @Shaun Let's hope mathemagics will improve their question and tell us if this answers the issue.

Comment: Apologies for the poor question, as well as any lack of clarity in how it was originally written. I am aware that there are counterexamples, but what I am curious about is if there are additional assumptions that can be made such that the statement itself holds.